Gaining additional information after Kruskal-Wallis by further comparing groups using Wilcoxon? (when two-way ANOVA is not possible)
I have the following experimental set-up, with the numbers being individuals in six groups:



Scenario
Treatment 1
Treatment 2
Treatment 3




A
28
27
27


B
28
28
28



What has been measured once is distance moved in mice based on treatments in two different scenarios. All individuals are unique and are not repeated among groups.
The research question was if the three treatments would differ in distance moved. To add another layer, we tested it in two different scenarios to see if that has an effect on the treatments.
Unfortunately, we could not perform a two-way ANOVA to test for interaction effect. We have instead done separate Kruskal-Wallis (KW) for each scenario, followed by Dunn's post-hoc if significant.

Q1. Would it be statistically sound to do a Wilcoxon between
Treatment 1 in A and B, then another for Treatment 2 in A and B, and
lastly one for Treatment 3 in A and B?
Q2. Likewise, would it it sound to do a Wilcoxon between Scenario A and B?

My reasoning is that for Q1, I will see if there is a difference between the treatments depending on the scenario. But at the same time, I'm aware that this is not a proper substitute for the interaction effect of a two-way ANOVA. It would be difficult to interpret if I found a significance between Treatment 1 in in A and B, but not for the rest. As such, I believe Q2 would be more reasonable as it would at least indicate whether the two scenarios as a whole has an effect.
I'm aware of p-hacking and it is something I wish to avoid. But it would be nice if it was possible to get additional information from the experiment, which is why I'm hoping for an answer! Also, are there any adjustments I need to take into considerations if any of these are feasible?

Welcome to Crossvalidated. Very well described question for a newcomer! Did you consider multiple regression with interaction (distance ~ treatment * scenario) ?

@rnso What I've tried are modelling two-way ANOVA, as well as GLM (with and without Poisson and some others). Some data transformations, such as logged, were also tried. But residuals aren't perfect, and QQ-plot is a very poor fit. I think this is caused by the large variance (sometimes nearly 9 times difference) and outlier values. Overall, there's a very strong right-skew. I'm a beginner and a student, so I'm not well-versed in statistics. So I'm afraid very specialized methods would be hard for me to understand, hence my "basic" question on Wilcoxon.

Part of your problem is that the research question you are asking is complex. You should simplify your question and not only the analysis will be easier but also the results will be much more applicable in real scenarios. It may be best to focus on 2 treatments rather than 3. Also 2 scenarios need not be separated for analysis but explained as characteristics of study population. Complex questions and analyses can only be considered hypothesis generating and not hypothesis proving.

@rnso Thank you. If you don't mind me asking, why do you think the research question is complex? As in, how would it be simpler with 2 instead of 3 treatments?

Most medical studies focus on finding if new treatment is better than standard treatment. Hence, my observation that your question is complex.

I will start by assuming that when you say "Wilcoxon", you mean Wilcoxon Rank Sum test (WRSt), aka Mann-Whitney U test (MWUt). I will also take into account the comment you made about unequal variances: "sometimes nearly 9 times difference".
Under this condition of heteroscedasticity, the MWUt, and the Kruskal-Wallis test (KWt) suffer from the Behrens-Fisher problem, in that, under the null, they exhibit inflated alpha errors (false positive rate > $\alpha$), even when the sample sizes are similar (as is your case). KWt further suffers from non-transitivity issues (i.e. under some conditions, when the null is false, it will fail to give significant results even when all the pairwise MWUt's are significant).
But we have the Brunner-Munzel test (BMt), which is basically a MWUt, but is not affected by the Behrens-Fisher problem. It is therefore often preferred to the MWUt (e.g. here), for the same reason that the Welch t-test is preferred to the "classic" Student's t-test. I am not aware of an equivalent for the KWt.
Note that the MWUt, BMt and KWt all 3 test the same null of stochastic equivalence (i.e. that, for randomly selected values X and Y from two populations, the probability of X being greater than Y is equal to the probability of Y being greater than X).
Q1; absolutely, you can run 3 BMt tests, to compare the 3 treatments accross the 2 scenarios. Of course with proper multiple comparison correction (MCC) (even if you only have 3 comparisons).
Q2; I am much more dubious here, because the effect of the scenario is conflated with the effect of the treatments; they can mask, or inflate, each other. Also, all the Scenario samples will not be i.d. (because the treatments are different, which possibly changed their distribution).
Q3; (I know, you did not ask it, but probably should have). I would also compare the treatments, within each scenario; that will tell you if treatments are different for a given scenario.
You mention "It would be difficult to interpret if I found a significance between Treatment 1 in in A and B, but not for the rest". I would instead view this as confirmation that there are interactions: some Treatments mask (or amplify) the effect of the Scenario (or reciprocally, Scenario masks/amplifies the effect of some treatments, but not others).
Q1 will tell you if/where Scenario makes a difference. Q3 will tell you if/where Treatment makes a difference. And the inconsistencies tell you about the interactions.
Alternatively, you could use a regression of your continuous DV (distance) against 2 categorical predictors (scenario, treatment), with interaction terms. You mention "non normal" residuals. In that case, the CI's and significance of the coefficients is in doubt, but the regression line is still the line which minimizes the sum of squared errors (this result is purely mathematical, not statistical; think of it as another descriptive stat). That alone should tell you something, and so would the relative contribution of the interaction term (relative to the other terms): e.g. how different are the regression lines with or w/o the interaction term?
Last, your sample size being large enough, you could even run bootstrapped regressions (as above), just to obtain the regression coefficients, and derive bootstrapped CI's of the coefficients (w/o worrying about normality).
In fact, I would probably run pairwise tests for each treatment between scenarios, and for each scenario, between treatments, just for exploratory analysis (but then w/o MCC, as no hypothesis would be tested), and then run the bootstrapped regression for my actual test (and hopefully, that regression would "explain" the findings from my exploratory analysis).

Thank you for the comprehensive answer! I'm aware of bootstrapping, but I'm hesitant to use it as I don't fully understand it and how reliable it would be (since I'd need to argue for my choice). But it's a possibility. As for exploratory analysis, I have a general question: do you know how this would be presented in an article? I don't think that would fall under results, right, since it's exploratory. But I don't think I've ever come across an article in my field doing exploratory analyses.

Wrt bootstrap, it may reassure you that the FDA us accepting statistical results based on bootstrap (e.g. see https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC8539859/), at least for some applications. Your exploratory analysis would not lead your results section, but could be used in it, after the "main", just to say that, btw, it supports the results presented earlier. Now, if the bootstrapped regressions tell 1 story, but the pairwise comparisons tell another story, you will need to dig some more, and explain why.
